# Make compound path in Adobe Illustrator by script

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

There are some compoundPathItems in myfile.ai

How can i run "Object > Compound Path > Make" or send "ctrl+8" from jsx? At line with comment ERROR HERE i get error message "A new object cannot be created at the specified location".

```
#target illustrator

if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var idoc = app.activeDocument; 
    var cp = idoc.compoundPathItems.add();
    var allPaths = activeDocument.pathItems;
    //Select objects
    for(var i = 0;i < allPaths.length;i++){
        allPaths[i].selected = true;
    }

    var selection = app.activeDocument.selection;
    for (var i=0; i<selection.length; i++) {
        selection[i].move (cp, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND); // move selected path inside the compound path ERROR HERE 
        selection[i].evenodd = true; // necessary to determine "insideness" or to make holes.  
    }

    alert(selection);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    app.executeMenuCommand("compoundPath");
```